# centos 6.0 : how to print to a Xerox laser printer

Tags: printing, centos-6

I use a centos 6.0. How can I print to the Xerox printer from my applications -- like LibreOffice, emacs, eclipse, chrome, etc ?

Comment: Have you added the printer?

Comment: I don't know how to add a printer!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add printer to an applicataion because a printer is an element of the operating system and not of the application.  All applictions takes the printers of the operating system.

You may want to add a new printer to your CentOS.  Simply go to System -> Administration -> Printer (or Printing), use the Add new printer icon.  Follow the instruction. (If your printer is a good network printer, it may be autodetected.  Else, note its IP address on a paper and use `HP Jetdirect`.)

Alternatively, you can browse the address 127.0.0.1:631 to have the web interface of CUPS.  This interface may be a little harder to use.